# Simple modrewrite rule with regex

Tags: mod-rewrite

This are my urls

```
http://test.aDomain.com/x-61bff
http://test.aDomain.com/x-ssmJhs54as65d4
http://test.aDomain.com/x-115545454
```

my rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^create-account create-account.php [L]
RewriteRule ^account account.php [L]
RewriteRule ^impress impress.php [L]


RewriteRule ^(x\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+) redirect.php?code=$1 [L]
```

The result is

```
http://test.aDomain.com/redirect.php
```

But why? it should be

```
http://test.aDomain.com/redirect.php?code=x-61bff
```

i dont get it ... can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mainly because you got the regex wrong:

1. the `/` between the host-name and the path is *really* part of the path (e.g. it is `/x-61bff` instead of `x-61bff`). however, your regex matches only an `x` at the very beginning, thus `/x-61bff` will *never* match.
2. the minus-sign has only a special meaning within square brackets (e.g. `[A-Z]`); outside it is just another character, there is no need to escape it

so your rewrite-rule really should look like:

```
RewriteRule ^/(x-[a-zA-Z0-9]*) redirect.php?code=$1 [L]
```